# How to fix the Default spinner theme style?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-manifest

I have made my custom theme in order to set my Window Title bar because of which my default spinner is using that theme and getting disturbed. 
This is the following **theme style** which I am using for Window Title bar:-

40dip
     @style/CustomWindowTitleBackground

```
 </style>

  <style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
<item name="android:background">#5a7210</item>
<item name="android:gravity">center</item>

  </style>
```

**Manifest**

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logok"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/TitleBarTheme">
        <activity
           android:name="com.bb2.kk.Activity_login"
         >
     <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


         >
    <item name="android:background">#5a7210</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>


      </style>
```

I want to know that can we use  two or more theme in one project,If yes then How can we use default theme for my spinner apart from my custom theme in order to fix my problem .